# Masked input Plugin with date limit

Tags: jquery, date, format

I use masked input on a input text field for a date in the MM/YYYY format.
( http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ )

My javascript code:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(".date").mask("12/2099");
});
```

And HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="date">
```

When I start to write something it take to the field the value 12/2099 and it's impossible to write other thing.

If in javascript mask I write 99/9999, users could write date that is false ... so I don't what I have to do ?

I want to users that they could write starting on 01/1990 until 12/2099, possible adding to the restrict with the value of the date + 20 years or something like that ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I think is good to have the masked input but I prefer to validate the input value cause these kind of plugins generally works with regex from inside.

My solution for this could be:

**(EDITED AND TESTED)**

Adding a div for a message

```
<form id="frm">
    <input type="text" class="date">
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me"/>
</form>
```

the js:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

            function verifyDate(datevalue) {

              var done = false;

              if(datevalue != null || datevalue != ''){

                //split the date as a tmp var
                var tmp = datevalue.split('/');

                //get the month and year
                var month = tmp[0];
                var year = tmp[1];

               if(month >= 1 && month <= 12){
                  if(year >= 1990 && year <= 2099){

                   //clean the message
                   clean();

                   //finally, allow the user to pass the submit
                   done = true;

                  } else {
                    $('#msg').html('Year must be from 1990 - 2099.');
                  }
               } else {
                  $('#msg').html('Month is invalid.');
               }
            }
            return done;
          }

          function clean() {
             $('#msg').html('');
          }

          jQuery(function($) {

             //mask the input
             $(".date").mask("12/2099");

             $('#frm').submit(function() {
                var datevalue = $('.date').val();
                return verifyDate(datevalue)           
             });

             $(".date").keyup(function(){
                //get the date
                var datevalue = $(this).val();

                //only if the date is full like this: 'xx/xxxx' continue
                if(datevalue.length == 7) {               
                  verifyDate(datevalue);
                } else {
                  clean();
                }
             });

          });

    </script>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: It's work well for the message and you understand what i want, but i didn't block the form submit, and the message is display when the field is clear. I start writing and it say to me the message until i write the good value. Do you have any idea to block form, for the message it's not important.

Regards.

Comment: let me try something in jsfiddle, i will be back in some minutes more and tell you

Comment: You're a genious !

Many Thanks Oscar.

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest additional solution. I've modified a bit Oscar's solution.
I've used [Josh Bush's](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) masked input plugin. This plugin was developed ONLY to lead user's input without any validation. I've combined leading with validation.
Here my code:

```
<script src="@Links.Scripts.MaskedInput_js"></script>
<script>
$.mask.definitions['y'] = '[12]';
$.mask.definitions['m'] = '[01]';
$.mask.definitions['d'] = '[0-3]';
$("#BirthDay").mask("d9/m9/y999", { placeholder: " " });

$("#BirthDay").keyup(function () {
    var datevalue = $(this).val();
    if (datevalue.trim().length == 10) {
        verifyDate(datevalue);
    }
})

function verifyDate(datevalue) {
    var done = false;
    if (datevalue != null || datevalue != '') {
        var tmp = datevalue.split('/');
        var day = tmp[0];
        var month = tmp[1];
        var year = tmp[2];
        var fromYear = 1900;
        var now = new Date();

        if (day >= 1 && day <= 31) {
            if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
                if (year >= fromYear && year <= now.getFullYear()) {
                    clean();
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    $('#msg').html('Year must be between' + " " + fromYear + " - " + now.getFullYear());
                }
            } else {
                $('#msg').html('Month is invalid');
            }
        } else {
            $('#msg').html('Day is invalid');
        }
    }
    return done;
}

function clean() {
    $('#msg').html('');
}
</script>
```

Of course, this is not a comprehensive client-side date validation (there is no ability here to validate such date as 30/02/2013, for example). I have to use for that server-side date validation.

But nevertheless, this solution minifies client's mistakes.

Comment: I didn't use the validation logic, but the more restrictive input mask is useful in any case