# input type=time is not supported in firefox need some alternative solution to implement it

Tags: html, angularjs

input type=time is not supported in firefox. can you suggest me some alternative solution to implement it using angularJS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular js input date on firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932253/angular-js-input-date-on-firefox)

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is for a `date` input, not a `time` input.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You could have checked previous questions. As mentioned in w3school docs about html5, date and time are not supported in Firefox.

You need to write the format.

This question is already asked. Check out this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932253/angular-js-input-date-on-firefox)

Comment: user3106167 is asking about `time`, not `date`.  Also, their question says that Firefox is not supported.  They've done their homework... No need to beat up on them!  Also, what does "you need to write the format" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a timepicker yourself, or add one that has already been made.
HTML5 support is still poor in some aeras, and alot of these input types are only included in the newest browsers.

You can find a timepicker library here:
http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timepicker/