# How to use HTML input "time" with Angular FormGroup?

Tags: html, angular, formgroups, mat-form-field, mat-input

I want to allow user edit only time in my datetime form-field, but when user submits form the value is `null`

```html
<form [formGroup]="activityForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="time" formControlName="dateTo">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I found that this works when the input type is set to "text" but with "time" somewhat does not.

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-q6lbvc?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by 12h format, with was default. Thought the last two digits supposed to be seconds not AM/PM, that is why I was getting `null`.

There is no support for `input=time` in Firefox:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932253/angular-js-input-date-on-firefox)

Thanks @Meqwz for examples:

- Firefox 96.0 [form field example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRJGP.png)
- Chromium [form field example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V58RI.png)

Comment: Who told you it isn't supported in FF?  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time  
https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_input_type_time